# How to subset .Rmd files in a directory using list.files

Tags: r, file

I use this code which I got from [this blog](http://edrub.in/blog20170730.html) to count the number of lines of code in my .R files in a particular directory:

```
# Load two packages
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
# Count your lines of R code
list.files(path = "/Users/", recursive = T, full.names = T) %>%
  str_subset("[.][R]$") %>%
  sapply(function(x) x %>% readLines() %>% length()) %>%
  sum()
```

I wanted to count the lines of codes in my .Rmd files as well and I tried this code:

```
# Count your lines of R code
list.files(path = "/Users/", recursive = T, full.names = T) %>%
  str_subset("[.][Rmd]$") %>%
  sapply(function(x) x %>% readLines() %>% length()) %>%
  sum()
```

I also tried using .R OR .Rmd but this is not working either:

```
str_subset("[.][R]$|[.][Rmd]$")
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is off :)
Try `str_subset("\\.Rmd$")`

Answer (score 0):

Besides the incorrect regex (`[Rmd]` is a [*character class*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html) that matches *either* “R” *or* “m” *or* “d”, not a sequence of the three letters “R”, “m”, “d”), this code is unnecessarily inefficient since it first lists *all* files and then filters them afterwards. Merge the two operations: `list.files` accepts an argument `pattern`.

Furthermore, your code misses files which end in `.r` or `.rmd`; it only finds `*.R`/`*.Rmd`.

As a matter of style, avoid using `T` and `F`: the two are *variables* that can be overwritten in user code! Always use `TRUE` and `FALSE` instead. These are reserved identifiers, this reduces sources of error.

Lastly, `list.files` has an alias: `dir`.

Taken together:

```r
dir(path = "/Users/", pattern = '\\.[Rr]md$', recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE) %>%
  sapply(function(x) x %>% readLines() %>% length()) %>%
  sum()
```

I should also mention that I’d be tempted to write the code as follows:

```r
dir(path = "/Users/", pattern = '\\.[Rr]md$', recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE) %>%
  lapply(readLines) %>%
  lengths()
  sum()
```

This is shorter and reads cleaner. It also avoids using the [error-prone](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Exceptions-Debugging.html#defensive-programming) `sapply` function. On the other hand, this way first reads *all* files into memory and then calculates their lengths: this is not ideal. The first, longer code uses substantially less memory if there are many RMarkdown files.